# windows phone 8 TTS - how to save the speech to wav file

Tags: windows-phone-8, text-to-speech, wavelet

With windows phone 8 TTS API, is there anyway to record/save the speech output from tts SpeechSynthesizer?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms586883.aspx)

So something like

```
SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
synth.SetOutputToWaveFile(@"C:\Test\Sample.wav");
synth.SpeakAsync("hello world");
```